# How to push a history entry and change address bar url without navigating to that url?

Tags: vue.js

I try to mimic how Pinterest (and a lot of other popular sites) achieved this.

When a user clicks a modal, the modal pops up, the address bar url changes, a new history entry is added, but the page doesn't reload. And when the user closes the modal, everything reverts to previous state with a new history is also added.

Vue-Router offers router.push, router.replace and router.go, but they don't achieve what I want. router.push would navigate to that url, but I am opening a modal which has an URL associated with it, not going to that url. router.replace replaces the current history entry, not adding new one.

What is the standard way to do this?

Answer (score -2):

Use Vue Router (google it) for this. Just keep in mind that stuff like this generally means a lot of work for very little gain.

With Vue Router you can set your app up so that page.com/book/Test directs you to page.com/book with the variable Test set.

I recommend setting your site up as a single file project using Webpack and the Vue plugin, and using that eith Vue router. Then you can get the functionality you want.